# How do I smooth the jagged edge of a surface plot in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plot, visualization

I'm using persp3D to plot one half of a 21x21 matrix. The hypotenuse of the triangle has jagged edges. I'd like to smooth them out so it looks like a proper triangle.

Any ideas? I'm open to using another plotting function.

[image: example from persp3D]

Comment: One way is to make the line down the "side" a sequence of decimal values, where the values are the 10s, 100s, whatever of the integer values.  Another would be to make the plot window smaller.

Comment: diagonal is what i meant by side there.  Haha

Comment: How are you getting 3D out of a (2-dimensional) matrix?  In any case, what's displayed is a correct an accurate plot of a bunch of rectangles, each one representing one element of your matrix.  If you want other shapes, you'll have to change the data itself.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I'm getting a 3D image by doing
 z<-as.matrix(read.csv(filename,header=FALSE))
 persp3D(z=z)

Comment: What I meant was that there isn't really a 3rd dimension in your dataset. You're just rotating a 2D field.

Comment: Right. This is using example data. I can add my actual data if you think it'd be helpful but I don't really see why it's necessary.